# Automatic Logout on from another active session

Tags: functions

I have a made **application over Wordpress** for premium user where user can see page **after logging** into his account.

but there is issue that same user can login form **multiple computer**, so I want to make function for the user session, when user login in Wordpress then **expires all other sessions**,

By this way I can prevent miss use of my Wordpress application.

I want a function that would make only **one current active session**.

Comment: This question seems perfectly alright. Why down votes? BTW, What have you tried so far? We would love to see some codes..

Comment: yes you are correct @Sisir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer has been updated because don't need to write function, only use `wp_destroy_all_other_sessions` function with `init`like this

```
add_action('init', 'wp_destroy_all_other_sessions');
```

Developed its plugin and publish on WordPress Download here :[One Active session](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-active-logged-in-session/)

Comment: OK, since you copy / pasted the `wp_destroy_other_sessions` built in function why not use that directly with the `init` hook?